# Toggling the className if the e.target.id is present inside the array on state

Tags: jquery, reactjs, state

I would like to toggle className of `<Panel>` if the roomId is present inside the `selectedRooms` array in the state. I thought something like below  to check if the roomId is present in the state but I can't quite come how to execute.

on the state rooms is array which is being mapped to render on the Modal. Then onSelectRooms allows me to save the clicked/selected rooms by the users in the selectedRooms array. rooms data looks like ["room01", "room02", "room03", "room04", "room05".......] `selectedRooms` data looks exactly the same but contains rooms that users have clicked. and I want to visually color the clicked/selected rooms which are on `selectedRooms` array

```
<Panel onClick={this.onSelectRooms} className={this.state.selectedRooms.includes() ? 'bg-success' : ''}>
```

```
export default class ExportReportRoomSelectionModal extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const roomOrder = configContext.value.roomOrder;

        this.state = {
            rooms: roomOrder,
            selectedRooms: []
        };

        this.onSelectRooms = this.onSelectRooms.bind(this);

    }

    onSelectRooms = (e) => {

        const { selectedRooms } = this.state;
        const { id } = e.target;

        //remove room

        if(selectedRooms.includes(id)) { 
            this.setState({
                selectedRooms: selectedRooms.filter((name) => name !== id)
            });

        //add room
        } else{
            this.setState({
                selectedRooms: [...selectedRooms, id]
            }); 
        }
    }


    render() {


        return (
            <Modal}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Print PDF</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <p>Number of rooms: {this.state.rooms.length}</p>
                    <p>Rooms:</p>

                    <Grid fluid={true}> 
                        <Row className="show-grid">
                            { this.state.rooms.map((roomName, i ) => 

                                <Col key={i}>
                                    <Panel onClick={this.onSelectRooms} className={this.state.selectedRooms.includes() ? 'bg-success' : ''}>  
                                        <Panel.Heading id={roomName}> 
                                            {roomName}                               
                                        </Panel.Heading>
                                    </Panel> 
                                </Col>
                            )}
                        </Row>
                    </Grid>

                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>

            </Modal>);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the shape of `selectedRooms` array? Do you only keep `id`s of rooms or rooms itself?

Comment: Hi devserkan, my array looks like this `["room14", "room13", "room20", "room21", "room22", "room16"]`

Comment: Can you provide `rooms` data as well, please? Your logic seems fine, you just need to pass the relevant pice to `.includes` I guess.

Comment: on the state `rooms` is array which is being mapped to render on the Modal. Then `onSelectRooms` allows me to save the clicked/selected rooms by the users in the `selectedRooms` array.

`rooms` data looks like `["room01", "room02", "room03", "room04", "room05".......]`

`selectedRooms` data looks exactly the same but contains rooms that users have clicked. and I wanna visually color the clicked selected rooms which are on `selected Rooms` array

Comment: So, they are both arrays of strings right? Then your code fine with `this.state.selectedRooms.includes(roomName) ? 'bg-success' : ''` If that does not work then there must be another problem.

Comment: You were right dev, thanks for you help